# Why do I get this error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df of true and false boolean expressions, and I'd like to compare them to print the dataframe node column to my .xlsx if is true, and to another xlsx column if false.

```
if data['equal'] == True:
    ws['I1'] = data['node2']
elif data['equal'] == False:
    ws['J1'] == data['#node1']
ws.save()
```

Error:

```
if data['equal'] == True:
```

Lil' example of data:

[image: data]

```
ws['J1'] `
```

is an example of a column header I'm trying to print to to my xlsx using openpyxl. Thanks

Comment: You're getting the error because `data['equal']` is a series of many values, and it makes no sense to compare a series to a single value.

Comment: I can't print to my excel file and i'm not sure what to do even though i tried using .all()

Comment: Is it nebulous? Why not ask for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to select the data row-wise. As mentioned in the comments, you can't use an if statement directly on an array of values but you can use that array as a mask to index your dataframe/numpy array.

While I might have misunderstood the exact nature of your problem, but you might be able to achieve the selection by using boolean masking, like this (with a simple example dataframe):

```py
>> df = pd.DataFrame({'mask': [True, False, True], 'data': [1, 2, 3]})
    mask  data
0   True     1
1  False     2
2   True     3

>> df[df['mask'] == True]  # select rows which are True
   mask  data
0  True     1
2  True     3

>> df[df['mask'] == False]              
    mask  data
1  False     2
```

Comment: Hope you can apply it to your situation! Good luck =)